# Issue Inlining circular shaped div's for my nav bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

hi will be available in the shape of circle. I got the code for responsive circle with text but the problem is this hat i am not able to inline two circles in one line . I tried float:left; as well as display:inline-block; but both doesn't work for me. Display:inline-block; inline the circles but the text inside it overlaps.
THIS is my HTML:

```css
    /*------NAV--BAR--*/
    * .fa-navicon{padding:8px; font-size:7vw ;}
    .nav-bar{position:absolute;z-index:5;width:100%; height:100%; background:grey; padding:10px;}
    .nav-bar input{ border:; outline:none; margin-left:10px;
      width:70%;
    }
    .nav-bar input::placeholder{color:grey; margin-left:10px;}
    /*--copied-code---*/
    .circle {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      margin: 2em 0;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #222;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .circle:after {
      display: block;
      padding-bottom: 30%;
      width: 30%;
      height: 0;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #ddd;
      content: "";
    }
    
    .circle__inner {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 30%;
      height: %;
    }
    
    .circle__wrapper {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .circle__content {
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 1em;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
      .circle__content {
        font-size: 2em;
      }
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .circle__content {
        font-size: 4em;
      }
    }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="nav-bar">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <i class="fa fa-close " style="font-size:7vw;color:#393e41; padding:3px; vertical-align:top; "></i>
    <div class="option-wrapper">
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="circle__inner">
        <div class="circle__wrapper">
          <div class="circle__content">Global</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="circle__inner">
        <div class="circle__wrapper">
          <div class="circle__content">Friends</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="circle__inner">
        <div class="circle__wrapper">
          <div class="circle__content">Classroom</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="circle__inner">
        <div class="circle__wrapper">
          <div class="circle__content">Games</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I want two or three circles on every line depending upon the user screen size.

Sorry if i did something wrong. This is my first quest. in stackoverflow.Thnks in advance.

Comment: Please can you check URL https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, adjust the browser size to view the responsiveness. You can also change the circle dimensions and font size depending upon your media-size.

If you need the full site to be responsive, I suggest to implement it with the popular CSS framework "Bootstrap", its pretty easy - [Bootstrap-Grid-HowItworks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

```css
.fa-navicon{padding:8px; font-size:7vw ;}
.nav-bar{position:absolute;z-index:5;width:100%; height:100%; background:grey; padding:10px;}
.nav-bar input{ border:; outline:none; margin-left:10px;
    width:70%;
}
.nav-bar input::placeholder{color:grey; margin-left:10px;}

.circle-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.circle {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .circle{
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .circle {
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <i class="fa fa-close " style="font-size:7vw;color:#393e41; padding:3px; vertical-align:top; "></i>
    <div class="option-wrapper">
        <div class="circle-wrapper">
            <div class="circle">Global</div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-wrapper">
            <div class="circle">Friends</div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-wrapper">
            <div class="circle">Classroom</div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-wrapper">
            <div class="circle">Games</div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-wrapper">
            <div class="circle">School</div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-wrapper">
            <div class="circle">College</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code worked for me! i want to to add these circles to my mobile website so i also used height and width and font-size to the main .circle properties instead of putting them inside media queries. Thanks for replying

Comment: @Pratham Vaidya, if it worked can you mark this as chosen answer.